# Raspberry Pi connected to Wifi, MAC also to Wifi but want an ethernet also direct between Pi and MAC

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, bridge

I have seen some similar questions posted but no firm response on how to do this.

Raspberry Pi 4, connected through WiFi on the network.  MAC is also connected to the WiFi Router.

What i want to do is connect my MAC's Ethernet to a switch and the RPi to the same switch so i can access the RPi on a wired connection instead of the WiFi, but want to leave the RPi connected to WiFi for internet and ancillary access.

I have tried a VLAN setup for my Ethernet port on the MAC, and tried the same network schema and different private one, but cannot get it all working together.

Please let me know if you have had a similar configuration work.

Thank you

Tony

Answer (score 0):

"but no firm response on how to do this" because you haven't actually said what "this" is. I presume by "MAC" you mean an Apple Mac.

The Pi (or indeed ANY computer) can independently configure network interfaces. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for details using the default `dhcpcd`.

I would't use a switch to connect a Mac to a Pi, just an Ethernet cable, but if you have a router I wouldn't normally use any direct connection.

Comment: you need an ethernet hub/switch for the ethernet network (subnet/VLan) whatever you want to refer to it to.  the MAC and Pi are both connected via wifi to the router which is connected to the internet... the ethernet side is a different LAN (wifi is 192.168.x.x and ethernet is 10.0.x.x  turning off the wifi router the VLAN works fine from the MAC point of view, and on the mac side even with wifi up... but the Pi cant handle the routing natively.  i installed VLan on Pi but there is no configuration info.

Comment: @TonyFaz You asked about connecting a Mac Ethernet to a Pi NOT connecting to a network. 

This detail (and detail of the network) belongs in your Question. If both networks have DHCP servers there is NO NEED to do anything, unless you want to use the lower priority network for a gateway. Indeed these are all described in the linked Answer *Advanced dhcpcd Configuration*.